# What is the meaning of キリ in this paragraph?

Tags: word-usage

Reading in NHk I came across this paragraph, and I cannot make out the meaning of キリ：

> さらに堀埜社長は、7月、異例の値上げに踏み切りました。といってもほとんどは1円から数円の値上げ、中には値下げした商品もあります。看板メニューの「ミラノ風ドリア」は299円から、300円に。
>
> 値上げのねらいは、「釣り銭を減らす」こと。すべてのメニューを50円単位の**キリ**のいい金額にすることで会計がスムーズになり、客と店員との接触の機会が減って、安心につながるというのです。値上げ後、釣り銭を6割削減する効果があったそうです。

Personally, I think it could be related to 切り　which means END, STOP, BOUND, so when I broke the sentence down it resulted in this:

すべてのメニューを50円単位の**キリ**のいい金額にすることで会計がスムーズになり。。。
all  menu を 50 yen unitの END, LIMIT? のgood amount of money に doing  で accounting が smooth に becomes.

But I am not sure.

Comment: You should probably add what you think it might mean, what you've researched, etc.  Otherwise it may be closed as a translation request.

Answer (score 3):

You're right; this usage of キリ is related to the first definition of 切り in [大辞林](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E5%88%87%E3%82%8A)

> きり 【切り・限▽り】
> 一
> ［2］ （ 名 ）
> ① 物事がそこで終わりになる切れ目。区切り。ひと区切り。 「 －のいいところでやめる」 「 －をつける」

The first usage example in the definition above is particularly relevant. [切りのいいところ](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E5%88%87%E3%82%8A%E3%81%AE%E3%81%84%E3%81%84%E3%81%A8%E3%81%93%E3%82%8D)でやめる means to stop doing something at an opportune or logical moment – for example, when one step in a multi-step process has been finished, rather than right in the middle of a step. Somewhat similarly, キリのいい金額 refers to an **amount of money** (金額) that is what we would call a [round number](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/round%20number) in English. In this particular case, it's clear from context that it means a price ending in -00 or -50. So ¥1550 or ¥300 would be キリのいい金額, while ¥1552 or ¥349 would not.